# Retrieving image files from referenced items in filtered items

Tags: podio, klipfolio

Being new to REST APIs (and APIs in general), I ran into some problems while trying to retrieve some Podio data using the Klipfolio web service, where I want to setup a simple dashboard with a list containing a name field from collected Podio and a image field from a reference field from the collected items.

So far I was led in the direction of 'bundling' and 'nesting', but I am not quite sure if this is the way forward.

In order to retrieve the filtered items, I have used the following POST method:

```
POST /item/app/11821547/filter/
```

Body:

```
{ 
"from": -1mr, 
"to": -0mr 
}
```

And then, from the items I here retrieve, I want to GET the referenced items, for instance using:

```
GET /reference/{ref_type}/{ref_id}
```

And finally, I want to get the image URL from the respective field in these referenced items, for instance using:

```
GET /item/{item_id}/value/{field_id}
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you only need to use one API call to the Podio [filter items](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/filter-items-4496747) endpoint in which you wrote above; POST /item/app/11821547/filter/.

In your POST body, you can filter down your results with the created to and from dates. For example, if you only want the items for the past month, you can use [Klipfolio's date parameters](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/216181877-Date-parameters-in-data-source-queries). Your POST body will look like this:

```
{
"filters": {
    "created_on": {
      "from": "{date.addMonths(-1).format()}",
      "to": "{date.today}"
    }
  }
}
```

This will return an API reponse of all items that were created within the past month. From here you can build a klip and manipulate the [JSON with xpath expressions](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215547118-About-JSON-and-XML-data-sources) to extract the image urls and names. All this information will be within the `@item/fields` array in your API response. You'll have to determine which field ID is used for the name and image url field. These are unique to each account.

An example of xpath to extract these values would be like so:

```
@/items/fields[field_id='id_number']/values/value
```

Where id_number is the exact id number for the field.

If you are unfamiliar with xpath expressions within Klipfolio, [here is a document](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215547118-About-JSON-and-XML-data-sources) that walks through this.